# Can FluentValidation work with nested collections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Can FluentValidation work with hierarchical collections? Can the following object with arbitrary number of Child nodes be validated?

```
public class Node
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

In very simple terms I'd like the following code to work:

```
public class NodeValidator : AbstractValidator<Node>
{
    public NodeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ChildNodes).SetCollectionValidator(new NodeValidator());
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

This line causes StackOverflow exception:

```
RuleFor(x => x.ChildNodes).SetCollectionValidator(new NodeValidator());
```

How can I validate property "Id" of a deeply nested object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid recursion in your ctor, I would correct your validator with

```
RuleFor(x => x.ChildNodes).SetCollectionValidator(this);
```

I gave it a try, and it seems to retrieve the validation errors correctly, but... I let you see if that's really what you need.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not actual anymore. `SetCollectionValidator` method is [deprecated](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-8.html#setcollectionvalidator-is-deprecated)

Instead, you should use `RuleForEach` and `SetValidator`. The proper code is:

```cs
RuleForEach(x => x.ChildNodes).SetValidator(this);
```